# Hydrangea leaves going brown

Tags: hydrangea

We just recently bought and installed a hydrangea about a month ago. We planted it and added organic fertilizer and have been watering it daily. It gets morning and mid day sun and shade in the afternoon. It is starting to brown on its leaves. What is causing this and how do we prevent it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities - Hydrangeas of this type prefer to be out of the midday sun, especially if the uv levels where you live are high - morning and evening, or dappled sun is fine. Second, you say you're watering daily, but that doesn't necessarily mean the root ball of the plant is getting enough water. You don't say how you're watering and how long for, but if your weather is warm and sunny (and even more so if its windy) this plant will need about a gallon of water per day until its been able to extend its roots into the soil to seek out its own supplies, which takes some time - up to Fall easily. If the weather is cool and not sunny, then about a gallon or two every 3 or 4 days should suffice.

So essentially, it depends what you're watering with and how long for...as well as whether its baking in hot sun in the middle of the day.